# What kind of reflection does Unreal use?

Tags: c++, performance, reflection, scripting, unreal-engine4

I know for a fact that unreal uses a reflection system in order to have C++ scripts. I also know that it uses macros in order to define how the variables should be reflected by the engine. Here comes what **i don't know**:

Are this macros **defining metadata** from within the code execution (filling lists, defining structs, etc...), or are they just **markers** for a parser that generates more C++ code, which then is used by the engine to know which variables to reflect?

It has to be one of this two, since I highly doubt that macros could help with parsing debug code, which is the only third option that I have found after investigating several C++ reflection systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unreal engine generates C++ code that is used for the reflection system.

> UHT parses the headers, builds up a set of reflection data, and then generates C++ code containing the reflection data (contributing to a per-module .generated.inl), as well as various helpers and thunk functions (per-header .generated.h).

From https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/blog/unreal-property-system-reflection

Comment: Yeah, sorry, stack overflow noob here XD